# How do I do a HTTP post request to a secured url?

Tags: javascript, json, httprequest

I am receiving this link containing API reference http://api.fang88.com/api/we_article/get_all_audited_we_article_
list
but when I click on it the browser says it is broken 
The person who gives this to me says it can not be opened via browser and that I need to do a HTTP post request of this url with empty parameters{}.

I have

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

and this json file

```
{
  "name": "fang88",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Fang88.com, Inc."
  ],
  "description": "Fang88",
  "keywords": [
    "Fang88",
    "Interview"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.6.3"
  }
}
```

It says if I open this I will get another json file.
How can I do this using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

app.post is telling Express JS to listen for requests to / and run the function when it sees one.
As it get posted, there will be success or failure or failure. And database operation takes place based on there is success or failure. So we mentioned the response on error as throw an error on failure and send response with "record updated!" string.
db.Operation.collection.insert <<<---is one kind of collection method for MongoDB.
example:

```
app.post('/todo', function(req, res) {
  dbOperation.collection('todo').insert(req.body,function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err
    res.send("Record added !");
  })
})
```

And in Controller.js:

```
    todo.createTask=function(){      //it is expression for ng-click parameter
  var data = [{                  //as button clicks, the variable data array is declared and with the values of object property.
    name: todo.model.txtTask,
    status:"Pending"
  }];
  $http.post("/todo",data).then(function(response){  //this is $http service shortcut method, used to send the data to specific URL, means it inserts new data based on given URL.
      alert(response.data);
    function(error){
      console.log(error, "Error!");
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please add some more explanation not just code so user understand it easily.

Comment: can you explain a little bit?